# CSS element will not become the width of the page when zoomed

Tags: css, width, viewport

http://jsfiddle.net/aN57Q/1/

When I zoom my page, an element will eventually stretch it and when it does you get a situation much like the one in the jsFiddle above.

The blue element represents the element stretching the page, it cannot be changed the rest is fair game. I need the red boxes to fill the page appropriately.

Thanks so much in advance!

```
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c"></div>

<div class="somethingBig">Blah!</div>

div {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.a { width: 100%; }
.b { width: 100vw; }
.c { width: 100%; }

.somethingBig {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? I don't see anything odd with zooming. What do you mean fill 'appropriately'?

Comment: Use the scrollbar at the bottom, the red blocks ARE NOT filling to the end (right) of the blue!

Comment: * When you are zoomed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is the same thing that happens when the browser window is smaller, such that the red bars are not as wide as the blue bar. They are only going 100% of the body, which becomes smaller than the overflowing blue.

You can do `min-width:600px;` on your "div" CSS.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thx soooo much man. Seriously hope the rest of your day goes swimmingly. Cheers!

Comment: See also [Make DIV cover 100% of viewport instead of 100% of Body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343612/make-div-cover-100-of-viewport-instead-of-100-of-body)